# Python : run a py program on another box

Tags: python

I have a Python script that scans my logs and reports all its findings. Is it possible that the script in my box (say Box A) can be executed for another box (say B) without copying it.

Do I really need to copy my Python script to Box B and then execute it from box A or there is a method by which staying in Box A I can connect to Box B run my python program for box B there get its output to and close the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your logs on box B can be accessed over the network (e.g., through a network share or FTP), then you could modify the script on box A to retrieve and process them. If they are not network accessible, then you'll need to copy either the script from box A to box B, or the logs from box B to box A.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Fabric](http://fabfile.org) to get various details from Box B while running in Box A.

Comment: That would still to copy my Python script to box B and run it there

Comment: Nope. You could run shell commands on the other box and get the result of it on the Box A.